# How can I jump to next page in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to scrape the results from [here](https://www.class-central.com/courses/recentlyAdded) using scrapy. The problem is that not all of the classes appear on the page until the 'load more results' tab is clicked.

The problem can be seen here:

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
class ClassCentralSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "class_central"
    allowed_domains = ["www.class-central.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'https://www.class-central.com/courses/recentlyAdded',
    )
    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                # allow=("index\d00\.html",),
                restrict_xpaths=('//div[@id="show-more-courses"]',)
            ),
            callback='parse',
            follow=True
        ),
    )

def parse(self, response):
    x = response.xpath('//span[@class="course-name-text"]/text()').extract()
    item = ClasscentralItem()
    for y in x:
        item['name'] = y
        print item['name']

    pass
```

Comment: Well what does the url of the second page look like? If its like www.website.com/Recently_Added/2 then that would be a really simple solution. Or are you actually just trying to get the data that appears in load more results?

Comment: it's not work. I don't know how to get url page 2 or call [Load the next ..]

Comment: We'll yeah that was just an example, I was saying if the url changes in an obvious pattern you could exploit that. And okay so you are just trying to get the results form the 'load more results' tab

Comment: how can do that ? I have no ideal. I think if you want get result from tab [get more ..] you must do something with rules ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second page for this website seems to be generated via AJAX call. If you look into network tab of any browser inspection tool, you'll see something like:

[image: firebug network tab]

In this case it seems to be retrieving a json file from https://www.class-central.com/maestro/courses/recentlyAdded?page=2&_=1469471093134

Now it seems that url parameter `_=1469471093134` does nothing so you can just trim it away to: https://www.class-central.com/maestro/courses/recentlyAdded?page=2
The return json contains html code for the next page:

```
# so you just need to load it up with 
data = json.loads(response.body) 
# and convert it to scrapy selector - 
sel = Selector(text=data['table'])
```

To replicate this in your code try something like:

```
from w3lib.url import add_or_replace_parameter 
def parse(self, response):
    # check if response is json, if so convert to selector
    if response.meta.get('is_json',False):
        # convert the json to scrapy.Selector here for parsing
        sel = Selector(text=json.loads(response.body)['table'])
    else:
        sel = Selector(response) 
    # parse page here for items
    x = sel.xpath('//span[@class="course-name-text"]/text()').extract()
    item = ClasscentralItem()
    for y in x:
        item['name'] = y
        print(item['name'])
    # do next page
    next_page_el = respones.xpath("//div[@id='show-more-courses']")
    if next_page_el:  # there is next page
        next_page = response.meta.get('page',1) + 1
        # make next page url
        url = add_or_replace_parameter(url, 'page', next_page)
        yield Request(url, self.parse, meta={'page': next_page, 'is_json': True)
```

Comment: response = json.loads(response.load) use this to counvert response is json to selector ? and yield Request(url, self.parse, meta={'page': next_page, 'is_json': True}) the last '}' in the end ?

Comment: I've edited `parse()` method in my answer to do what your parse does but with pagination. I haven't tested the code but I think you can fix some typos if you find them yourself :)